# Constraints with UIScrollView and UIView

Tags: ios

I have a UIViewController which has half screen UIScrollView. This is being designed in IB with all required constraints and works fine. I've couple of UIViews (xib) files and individually setup properly with right constraints for each objects on UIViews. Now when i load and add these UIViews to UIScrollView, all UIView loose it's constraints and scrollview show UIViews even beyond screen. What i want is to show the UIViews only within the UIScrollView and when I scroll, to right (horizontal scroll), it show the second UIView rather showing the remaining part of first UIView.

How can i solve this problem? Thanks for your responses.

Comment: How are you adding the views to the scrollView. Programmatically or through IB?

Comment: programmatically   UIView *dashboard = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [dashboard setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollPresenter.frame.size.width, self.scrollPresenter.frame.size.height)];

Answer (score 1):

To properly use autolayout within scroll view you need to add an UIView as container for the rest of the subviews you want to add.

So the structure will be like this

[image: Structure for scroll view with autolayout]

Then you can add all of your subviews to `View - As Container`
For more detail you can follow this tutorial
[How to make AutoLayou work on A ScrollView](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/)